# trying to remove *.php from anchor href's with sed

Tags: html, regex, sed, grep

```
grep -r 'href="[^"]*\.php"' .
```

That tells me (in theory) all the files that have anchor href's ending in *.php in them. A quick glance over the output confirms this.

So I then try to remove the *.php from these anchor tags with sed and it isn't working (no files are changed). Here's what I tried to use in sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/href="([^"]*\.php)"/href="$1"/g' *.php *.xml
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack the `-r` switch in your command, or you need to backslash the parentheses.

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/href="([^"]+)\.php"/href="\1"/g' *.php *.xml
```

And the captured group is not `$1` (like in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)) but `\1`

Comment: Doesn't seem like that did anything either :(

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you replace by the same, try this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/href="\([^"]*\)\.php"/href="\1"/g' *.php *.xml
```

Comment: Seems like this would turn `<a href="whatever.php">` into `<a href="">`. I want it to be turned into `<a href="whatever">`. ie. remove the *.php but don't remove the href value all together.

Comment: @neubert: it is corrected. But note that it is written nowhere in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these work for me when I tested it.

Using `sed`

```
sed -i.bak -re 's|href="([^"]*)\.php"|href="\1"|g' *.php *.xml
```

Using `Perl`

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's|href="([^"]*)\.php"|href="$1"|g' *.php *.xml
```